# How to get drand48_r in macos?

Tags: c++, macos, random, openmp

I really need to use drand48_r generator, but it appears ther isn't one in macosx. I've been searching for an answer for a while, but the only thing I learned is that there isn't one. But i need it to be thread-safe so is there any way to write it on my own? Is it gonna be sa

```
struct drand48_data
{
unsigned short int __x[3];  /* Current state.  */
unsigned short int __old_x[3]; /* Old state.  */
unsigned short int __c;     /* Additive const. in congruential formula.  */
unsigned short int __init;  /* Flag for initializing.  */
unsigned long long int __a; /* Factor in congruential formula.  */
};

double drand48_r (unsigned short *_x) {
return erand48(_x);
}
```

and in main:

```
// declare state struct for drand48
drand48_data* _drand_structs = new drand48_data[omp_get_num_threads()];

#pragma omp parallel
cout << "Hello, World from " << omp_get_thread_num() << "/" << omp_get_num_threads() << " Random:" << (2.0 * drand48_r(_drand_structs[omp_get_thread_num()].__x) - 1) << endl;

return 0;
```

but drand_48 always returns -1. What is wrong with it, any ideas?

Comment: You tag the question with C++. So why not `<random>` or `boost::random`?

Comment: Actually I dont want to use any of boost. I need parallel rand function provided by C/C++ itself.

Comment: `<random>` is provided by C++ standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `omp_get_num_threads()` outside of a parallel region always returns 1 since only one thread (the master thread) executes code outside of those regions. You should use `omp_get_max_threads()` instead. Also it is a Good Idea<sup>TM</sup> to initialise the `__x` member. The equivalent of `srand48(seed)` would be:

```
.__x[0] = 0x330E;
.__x[1] = (unsigned short)(seed & 0xffff);
.__x[2] = (unsigned short)(seed >> 16);
```

Apart from that, `drand48_r()` is the **reentrant** version of `drand48()`. Note that *reentrancy* is not the same as *thread-safety*, with the latter being what you probably need. In GLIBC (e.g. Linux) `erand48()` keeps track of the last value in a global variable and is therefore not thread-safe (nor is it reentrant), but on OS X it does not modify global variables (it also does not keep track of the last output) and is therefore reentrant (when both calls are passed disjoint `xsubi` arrays). It is also safe to make multiple calls to `erand48()` from different threads as long as no other thread calls `srand48()` or `lcong48()`. The reason is that all PRNGs share the multiplicative and additive constants used in the congruent formula.

If you need to support different constants in each thread, you should probably directly copy the implementation of `drand48_r()` from GLIBC.